# List items from RSS feed in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Trying to list out the items from a blog rss feed. I've add the following controller:

```
   /**
     * @Route("/rss", name="rss",
     *      options={"sitemap" = true}
     *     )
     */
    public function rss(){
        $rss = simplexml_load_file('https://somesite.wordpress.com/feed');

        return $this->render('default/rss-reader.html.twig', array(
            'rss' => $rss,
        ));
    }
```

Have the following in my twig template:

```
{% for item in rss %}
    {{ item.item.title }}
    {{ item.item.link }}
{% endfor %}
```

I previously had just item.title, but then that showed the title for the blog site as opposed to each blog. When I use this, it only shows the first post and doesn't continue.

Comment: You can use http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html for easier navigation.

About posts. I checked your provided XML file, it only contains one post.

Comment: @revengeance the actual blog is wattdoesituse.wordpress.com, was trying to use a generic address so as not to be be spammy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`simplexml_load_file()` (https://php.net/simplexml_load_file) returns a `SimpleXMLElement` https://php.net/simplexmlelement object.

So it depends on the XML structure, RSS feed can be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Mon site</title>
        <description>Ceci est un exemple de flux RSS 2.0</description>
        <lastBuildDate>Sat, 07 Sep 2002 00:00:01 GMT</lastBuildDate>
        <link>http://www.example.org</link>
        <item>
            <title>Actualité N°1</title>
            <description>Ceci est ma première actualité</description>
            <pubDate>Sat, 07 Sep 2002 00:00:01 GMT</pubDate>
            <link>http://www.example.org/actu1</link>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Actualité N°2</title>
            <description>Ceci est ma seconde actualité</description>
            <pubDate>Sat, 07 Sep 2002 00:00:01 GMT</pubDate>
            <link>http://www.example.org/actu2</link>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

So here, you try to loop throught "channel" tag.

Try using xpath https://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php to retrieve the `item` tags as array of `SimpleXMLElement`.